# Rails - single ID for multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, polymorphism, barcode

I'm building an app which will allow a user to scan the barcode on a 'shelf', 'box' or 'product' which will then bring up that particular item or all the associated items.

As these are all separate models with their own ID's, I need a global ID table.

I was thinking of a polymorphic table called 'barcodes'

**barcodes**

- id
- barcode_number
- barcodable

Is there an easy way to do this? Or is polymorphic the best way?

Answer (score 1):

Create a model `Barcode` (which will eventually have a field `number` or `code`):

```
class Barcode < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Then, every model that has a barcode will have a field in the table named `barcode_id`:

```
class Shelf < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :barcode
end

class Box < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :barcode
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :barcode
end
```

And you will have access to that barcode like this:

```
@shelf.barcode
```